# Hibernate C3P0 Issue

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

I  am trying to use the c3p0 settings , to enable the application to auto discard a stale connection, and reestablish the connection automatically.I have set the configuration properties as below in the sessionfactoryprovider class :

```
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", c3p0
                .get("minPoolSize") != null ? c3p0.get("minPoolSize")
                : "1");
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", c3p0
                .get("maxPoolSize") != null ? c3p0.get("maxPoolSize")
                : "50");
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.timeout", c3p0
                .get("maxIdleTime") != null ? c3p0.get("maxIdleTime")
                : "900");
configuration.setProperty(
                "hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts",
                c3p0.get("acquireRetryAttempts") != null ? c3p0
                                .get("acquireRetryAttempts") : "30");
configuration.setProperty(
                "hibernate.c3p0.acquireIncrement",
                c3p0.get("acquireIncrement") != null ? c3p0
                                .get("acquireIncrement") : "5");
configuration.setProperty(
                "hibernate.c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod",
                c3p0.get("idleConnectionTestPeriod") != null ? c3p0
                                .get("idleConnectionTestPeriod") : "60");
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.initialPoolSize", c3p0
                .get("minPoolSize") != null ? c3p0.get("minPoolSize")
                : "1");
configuration.setProperty(
                "hibernate.c3p0.maxStatements",
                c3p0.get("maxStatementsPerConnection") != null ? c3p0
                                .get("maxStatementsPerConnection")
                                : "0");
configuration.setProperty("preferredTestQuery", "select 1 from dual");
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin",
                "true");
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout",
                "true");
configuration.setProperty("testConnectionOnCheckin", "true");
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery",
                "select 1 from dual");
```

I don’t find any logs in the application , trying to execute the test query, nor is it recovering after a db restart. "show_sql"  s set to true in the properties file, and in the logs, I can see the other queries executing.
**The package versions are as follows :**
    C3P0 = 0.9.1.2;
    HibernateAnnotations = 3.3;
    Hibernate = 3.3;

Could someone please suggest how I should go about debugging this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the logging level for c3p0 to debug in your log4j-configuration:

```
log4j.category.com.mchange=DEBUG
```

Comment: As suggested , I have set the log level to DEBUG.  I can see all these properties being set in "SessionFactory" . But, the query is still not getting executed at periodic intervals .

Comment: Is it using your settings? Check that the property names are correct and verify that C3P0 is really using your settings. Last time I was setting up c3p0, there was something weird in the configuration properties names (with "hibernate.c3p0." vs. without). I ended up setting the values directly to C3P0's ComboPooledDataSource in Spring configuration-xml, which seemed to solve it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion to set the log level to debug. That helped in finding the root cause of the issue. It turned out that I was not using c3p0ConnectionProvider at all. Some other Connection Provider was set be default , as a result of which the propoerties were not getting picked up